# Parsing FTP LIST reply in C++

Tags: c++, parsing, ftp, libcurl, ls

I have been unsuccessful in parsing the following reply from libCurl FTP listing.

```
ftplister = fopen("ftp-full-list", "wb"); /* b is binary, needed on win32 */ 

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    /* Get a file listing from sunet */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, furl.c_str() );
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, usrpwd.c_str());

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &write_flist);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, ftplister);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */ 
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }

  fclose(ftplister); /* close the local file */   
}
```

The write_flist is

```
size_t  semperCloudBackup::write_flist(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
   FILE *writehere = (FILE *)stream;
  return fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, writehere);
}
```

Giving me an output shown below

```
03-26-07  05:23AM       <DIR>          html
03-26-07  04:27AM       <DIR>          laptop
03-26-07  03:16AM       <DIR>          images
03-27-07  11:00PM                 6397 index.html
03-26-07  03:45AM                10186 index1.html
```

I have to
1. Find if its a directory or file
2. Store the file along with its size (I am guessing in an array) to do some calculations with the size.
3. Store the directory names separately

Any help would be appreciated, a novice here. Thank you

After a lot of searching, I think I found something in perl but I wanted it in C++

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @elements = split /\s+/, $_;
    if ( $elements[2] eq '<DIR>' ) {
        print "Directory: ",$elements[3], "\n";
    }
    else {
        print "The size of $elements[3] is $elements[2] bytes.\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
03-26-07  05:23AM       <DIR>          html
03-26-07  04:27AM       <DIR>          ibm-laptop
03-26-07  03:16AM       <DIR>          images
03-27-07  11:00PM                 6397 index.html
03-26-07  03:45AM                10186 index1.html
```

I also found this [ftpparse](http://cr.yp.to/ftpparse.html)

To read each line separately (although is of not complete use) I used the following:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
      // a string to store line of text
      string textLine;
      // try to open a file
      ifstream ifs("sample_file.txt", ifstream::in);
      if (ifs.good())   { // if opening is successful
            // while file has lines
            while (!ifs.eof()) {
                  // read line of text
                  getline(ifs, textLine);
                  // print it to the console
                  cout << textLine << endl;
            }
            // close the file
            ifs.close();
      } else
            // otherwise print a message
            cout << "ERROR: can't open file." << endl;

      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just as a reminder of how ugly FTP is : the output of the command is not standardized in any way. According to the original RFC, the server is free to send you any kind of response it wants.

Comment: I totally understand Daniel, when I googled the same, I got varied answers and realised the problem. But the server is sending only that reply as its a private FTP server.